# How do you zoom out of CS50 IDE? I accidentally zoomed in and I don't know how to get it back to the original size

Tags: cs50

This shows the zoomed in image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE, `ctrl +` will zoom in, `ctrl -` will zoom out when cursor is in the edit tab.